# DunglasApiBundle - Trying to get the bundle to use Named Constructors rather than public constructor

Tags: api, symfony, bundle, api-platform.com

I'm using the Dunglas api-platform bundle (https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform) for a new app.

Setup and installation went fine, GET requests are working.

While trying to create new objects using POST requests, I received errors about having a private constructor. My models are all made using a private constructor, and using named constructors instead.

Ideally i'm either looking for a way to have the bundle call my Named constructors, ... or someone to tell me my approach is completely wrong.

Services.yml

```
services:
    resource.player:
        parent:    "api.resource"
        arguments: [ "Name\\Space\\Player" ]
        tags:      [ { name: "api.resource" } ]
```

Player Object

```
class Player
{
    private $name;
    private function __construct()
    {
    }
    public static function withName($playerName)
    {
        $player = new Player();
        $player->name = $playerName;
        return $player;
    }
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

Settings are pretty much all out of the box, following the introduction and setup in the documentation. I've skimmed through the Factory thing briefly - hoping that i'd be able to use a factory to create the objects, allowing me to call my own named constructors - but that doesn't seem to do what i think it does.

Any input regarding the use, boundaries or the setup is well appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API Platform (like most Symfony and Doctrine related libraries) is not designed to work with immutable objects like this one.

I suggest to create a typical mutable Entity as suggested in the doc:

```
class Player
{
    private $name;

    public static function setName($playerName)
    {
        $this->name = $playerName;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

If you really want to keep your immutable model, you'll need to implement yourself the `Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccessorInterface` and use a CompilerPass to make API Platform using your own implementation. You will probably need to submit a patch to API Platform and to the Symfony Serializer Component to update the reference of the given object too because currently, both serializers actually update the current object and will not use the new instance returned by your `with` method.

I strongly encourage you to switch to typical mutable entities.